# Typescript: Generic function with enums

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am using several enums as global parameters.

```
enum color {
    'red' = 'red',
    'green' = 'green',
    'blue' = 'blue',
};
enum coverage {
    'none' = 'none',
    'text' = 'text',
    'background' = 'background',
};
```

I merge all enums to a type `myEnums`.

```
type myEnums = color | coverage;
```

Now I want to check and access values of the enums. For instance:

```
// Returns undefined if the argument value is not a color.
function getColor(value: string): color | undefined{
    if(value in color) return value as color;
    return undefined;
}
```

Because there are several enums, I want to create a generic function to access all of my enums. I tried the following:

```
function getParam<T extends myEnums>(value: string): T | undefined {
    if(value in T) return value as T;
    return undefined;
}

getParam<color>('red', color);        // => should return 'red'
getParam<coverage>('test', coverage); // => should return undefined
```

But the Typescript compiler says:
**'T' only refers to a type, but is beeing used as a value here.'**.

So I added an argument `list: T` to the function, but then Typescript assums that the argument `list` has the type `string` (and not `object`).
**The right-hand side of an 'in' expression must not be a primitive.**

```
function getParam<T extends allEnums>(value: string, list: T): T | undefined {
    if(value in list) return value as T;
    return undefined;
}
```

So how can I call a generic function using `T` as an enum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`enum` is a special data structure in TypeScript.

If you want to put a restriction on generic you need to use `typeof Enum` instead.

In your example, you expect `typeof color | typeof coverage` and not `color|coverage`.

Because the last one is a union of values whether the first one is a union of enums.

COnsider this example:

```js
enum color {
    'red' = 'red',
    'green' = 'green',
    'blue' = 'blue',
};
enum coverage {
    'none' = 'none',
    'text' = 'text',
    'background' = 'background',
};

type myEnums = color | coverage;

const hasProperty = <Obj, Prop extends PropertyKey>(obj: Obj, prop: Prop)
    : obj is Obj & Record<Prop, unknown> =>
    Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, prop);



function getParam<Keys extends PropertyKey, Value, E extends Record<Keys, Value>, Key extends keyof E>(enm: E, key: Key): E[Key]
function getParam<Keys extends PropertyKey, Value, E extends Record<Keys, Value>, Key extends PropertyKey>(enm: E, key: Key): Value | undefined
function getParam<E extends typeof color | typeof coverage, Key extends keyof E>(enm: E, key: Key): E[Key]
function getParam<E extends typeof color | typeof coverage, Key extends string>(enm: E, key: Key): undefined | E
function getParam<E extends typeof color | typeof coverage | Record<string, unknown>, Key extends keyof E>(enm: E, key: Key): E[Key] | undefined {
    return hasProperty(enm, key) ? enm[key] : undefined
}

const y = getParam(color, 'red');        // => color.red
const x = getParam(coverage, 'undefined'); // => undefined
const x2 = getParam({}, 'undefined'); // => unknown

const higherOrder = (key: string) => getParam(color, key)

const z = higherOrder('red') // typeof color | undefined
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-EMWYWsa1pHFA1FVuEhJlBUUDRMYwEMvMWQoH0hAkPg+IMAwAD02n-FByAgtQpQGDJtjya6jYekpKiXloqniepmm6fpjnVlg0mVLYABMFk7tZaBSA5-jljRpDOXp5B-B83wgFJpmVFUZyMFUagdM8ajGPMxqrKhICMDxUXblZEA2dk3HxeUlQAF7GElKVpRlyDzGp4VQC5sHHrkYkhd+JBAA)

Please keep in mind, I'm not sure how you want to handle higher order functions so I  just returned a union of `enum` and `undefined` in last example

As for this line `if(value in T)`: `T` is a type and you can not treat is as a runtime value.

Comment: Two questions about your answer: (1) It is possible to use a `unknown` type as argument? The function should return the enum value (if it exists), otherwise undefined. For example: ````let input : unknown = 'blue'; let result = getParam(color, input);````. (2) It is possible to return the type `Partial<keyof typeof color>;` (in case of colors) and `Partial<keyof typeof coverage>;` and so on? Of course only if the key exists, otherwise it should be `undefined`.

Comment: It is completely changes the logic. DO you want to make super generic `getParam` function?

Comment: This comes from my old JS setup (maybe take a look at my getter functions : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69129503/typescript-access-values-from-a-nested-global-object-typ-string-cannot-be-u). I've to check user input which is `unknown`. Also I dont want to create a function for all of my global parameters (my enums).

Comment: if user input is unknown - we can remove all `enums` related logic, right?

Comment: My approach is the following: a websocket emmits data to my client which is unknown. The only thing I know is the component and the slot name which is targeted. Imagine, the slot name is `color`. I've to check if a valid color is passed to that slot. At this point I want to be sure the data is correct and work with this correct data - for example after checking if the `color` value is valid, I want that the color variable has the type `Partial<keyof typeof color>`. So you can compare this to a select box / dropdown menu. Because of that I need the enums and my global properties (valid values).

Comment: @michaelT made an update. you can pass any object. if it does not work for you please provide your case scenarios an the question

Answer (score 4):

I think the key is a proper typing of `T`, you have to tell TS, that T is "enum-definiton-like" object. I've poked around and found this, more or less working

I have something like this in one of my projects:

```js
export function parseEnum<E, K extends string>(
  enumDef: { [key in K]: E },
  str: string | undefined
): E | undefined {
  if (str && str in enumDef) {
    return enumDef[str as K] as E;
  }
  return undefined;
}
```

So, that's what works for "normal enum" and you want to use it "sum" of enums.

Fortunately, due to way enums are implemented in JS&TS, you can just merge enums definition objects like this:

```js
const myEnums = {...coverage, ...color }
// typeof myEnums = coverage | color;
```

and it works:

```js
const x = parseEnum(myEnums, 'x');
// typeof x = coverage | color | undefined;
```

Typescript playground [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=25&ssc=35&pln=1&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAMwK4DsDGMCWEVzAQygGdgBRFJAWwB5SAaOAaTlBmBQBMi4iYpMUAcwB8ACgBQcFhUoARYAgBccAN5wA2gGtgATzgCmAXWWk4AXzqSefZb35C4AHzioOCgcA7iAlCacvOdxRPVStMBDhROzgAMhjrKH1cdip5BG9QqSkoYBgkKGSZNPVo-G5GQzgyuFIAbiszKxy8goC3BA8OesbxFMo4NAgAG2hMrIByHI5xuABeOEnPccsshcEc9hn58fXgTZWJgCMhpGAthePT5fEzet6ZAYgAN2AofEFgMalxlBwzuYWv2C11W4zYIBg5zBrBBR3waE06wgrihh3hiKgyM411u4nEgxQvDglB05Co3HmKgAdDTBi83h8GDSqYMRokegSiSAAQRiGQZKISWTKEQGOMQONvLUgA)

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by the answers here and after several tries, I've found the best practice and the most simplified version for me so far.

```js
enum MyEnum {
    Value1 = 'one',
    Value2 = 'two',
};

let traverse_enum = <ENUM_AS_TYPE>(ENUM_AS_VALUE: Record<string, ENUM_AS_TYPE>): ENUM_AS_TYPE => {
    let key: string = '';
    for (key in ENUM_AS_VALUE) {
        console.log(`${key}: ${ENUM_AS_VALUE[key]}`);
    }
    return ENUM_AS_VALUE[key];
};
traverse_enum<MyEnum>(MyEnum);
```

I think what's most important is figuring out that `enum` can be used as both a value and a type, which will allow it to be integrated into the JavaScript code after compiling, while most other TypeScript features will be completely removed afterward.

It's a pretty confusing point, and you need a bridge to tell TypeScript the relation between the `enum` as a type and the `enum` as a value. I use `Record<string, ENUM_AS_TYPE>` here. So the solution to your question is:

```js
function getParam<ENUM_AS_TYPE>(value: string, ENUM_AS_VALUE: Record<string, ENUM_AS_TYPE>): ENUM_AS_TYPE | undefined {
    if(value in ENUM_AS_VALUE) return value as ENUM_AS_TYPE;
    return undefined;
}
```

[A complete solution to your question at TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAcwKZQAoEMBOWC2APAKIByAqgLID6AggMrUAqAmhsQHwAUAblgDYhUALkQBnKDhhhkAGkRkqdRgDVaAGXLFRAJVQQ4OACaEJUmfMU0GzNpwCUoq8tvtEAH0TgjqYNNRGiADeAFCI4YgwwLwCQpFIzjZqmsT2iDjoIDhIfIKoiFhiChTWjKzsANxhERlQWUjevv5GVQC+ISGoYCD4iAb8hsHV4QDkGUYjiAC8iGMBI7LDs8gZXZMzIyuoa4sRswBGeesHR4utVZ3dvQY8qHhoQ3sjYAiox8+vC0sjUKgAHlB3r8AV8nvssBAANYrODed7gqEwuFnC4GMBiOD8VAAOgGyC4aEwuAIhH6hm4cwm8jJOHs9gqez2AHomdMOOIABaw-iBWr1WbjEYhNEYrG4uD4wnYPBEG53LBoCm-CQLPpwW73VB0hkstmc7m8zLZLxgHx+MABEJMgBUIVIcF+iCgHKwUGKShs5WIBVN7tK1GSWgKGSdHPyYgI+RgPjAsD8d0QAHcw0gIAJ+NJkKH8qBILAEABCELWplAA)